# How do I delete the committed files from Github?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, git, version-control, github, project

My project is [here](https://github.com/deeptechtons/Plug) [the link is not for marketing thing as many might think], I am entirely new to Git and Github and I Use Git Extensions with Visual Studio 2008. I committed the file, directory Plug.Sln and Samples into Github, now

1. How the heck do I remove it from them & leave no trail that file existed in my repository?[on github, but make them remain in local repository]
2. I want to untrack these checked in Files in Visual Studio[I mean like, how do I get it to state it was before checking in these]
3. How do I revert to a last committed version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Github has a help section for this situation.  You can view it [here.](http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/)  That will remove them if they never existed.

If you want to keep them around, make a copy of the file **before** you follow the github guide.  Once you have removed them from your repository, add them back to your working directory, and add than add them to your [.gitignore file](http://help.github.com/ignore-files/) to keep git from tracking them.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to remove the file from version control.  Check out [How to stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/git-removing-a-file-from-source-control-but-not-from-the-source) for a solution.

Comment: That question deals with keeping the file in the repository, but not tracking it anymore.  The OP sounds like he wants to completely remove it and leave no trace that it existed.  Two entirely different processes with different results.