# GIT add revert in my case (keep changes)

Tags: git, github

After I made changes on a file. I use `git add FILE_NAME`.

Then, I would like to revert it as **not added** but meanwhile **keep the changes**, how to do this?

Comment: I think it's already answered [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/git-removing-a-file-from-source-control-but-not-from-the-source

Comment: @VladimirKadalashvili No, it's not answered. Mellon wants to **unstage** file added to index before commit, not remove commited file from repository (at last that's how I understand this question)

Comment: When you do `git status` it will already say what you have to do to unstage files.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`git reset -- FILE_NAME` will do it.

[See the `git reset` manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset):

> This means that `git reset <pathspec>` is the opposite of `git add <pathspec>`

Comment: Note this works *even if the file was untracked* prior to adding, and you want to unstage (un-add) it but preserve it (keep the changes), and make it untracked again.

Comment: `$ git reset --` to unstage everything

Answer (score 4):

```
git stash save 
git stash apply
```

they will all be unstaged

Answer (score 2):

you could use

`git reset --mixed -- <filename>`

if you use --hard, you would discard all your changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git reset`