# remove a file from GIT control

Tags: git, github, git-svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git - removing a file from source control (but not from the source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/git-removing-a-file-from-source-control-but-not-from-the-source)

I have a `.classpath` file which is currently in GIT repository.

After I pulled from remove repository(`git pull origin master`). How can I remove this file from GIT control, I mean `NOT to delete` this file from my computer **but** remove it from GIT version control. (Because this file is not needed for version control).

**P.S.**

I tried `git rm <path-to>/.classpath` , but then my whole project complains about wrong class path, why git rm delete my file instead of remove from version control ???

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Use `git rm --cached` to remove from the index but not the working tree.

After that, you should add `.classpath` to your .gitignore file, to prevent it from being committed again.

Comment: how to add to .gitignore , can u please be more specific ?

Comment: `git help ignore` or search the web - obviously post any gitignore question once you've tried

Comment: At the top of your directory, create a file named ".gitignore" and put `.classpath` into it. You can also use wildcards to ignore files matching a certain pattern (e.g., `*.class` to ignore all compiled Java classes). You might also be able to do .gitignores in subdirectories (which then only apply to that part of the project), but I forget. See http://linux.die.net/man/5/gitignore

Comment: So, I create .gitignore file and put the file name into the file , right?

Comment: Yes, that will work for a single file like `.classpath`. I would also recommend committing the `.gitignore` file so that other developers consume it and also don't commit `.classpath` by accident.

Comment: Do I need to specify the full path of the .classpath file or I only need to put the file name no matter where it is (Of course it is must under project folder)

Comment: Just the name is fine-- `.gitignore` patterns automatically apply to all subdirectories.

Answer (score 18):

> why git rm delete my file instead of remove from version control ???

Because that's what it says it will do.

```
$ git help rm
NAME
       git-rm - Remove files from the working tree and from the index

SYNOPSIS
       git rm [-f | --force] [-n] [-r] [--cached] [--ignore-unmatch] [--quiet]
       [--] <file>...

DESCRIPTION
       Remove files from the index, or from the working tree and the index.
       ... When --cached is given,
       the staged content has to match either the tip of the branch or the
       file on disk, allowing the file to be removed from just the index.

OPTIONS
      ...

       --cached
           Use this option to unstage and remove paths only from the index.
           Working tree files, whether modified or not, will be left alone.
```

As Platinum Azure says, use `git rm --cached` to only remove it from source control, and use `.gitignore` to keep it out and stop it showing in `git status`.