# gitignore file not working properly

Tags: git, version-control

I am trying to ignore the .pyc files in my folder and do not want to add them to my repository and i already created the gitignore file.

My gitignore file looks like this:

```
#python specific
*.pyc

##generic files to ignore
*~
*.lock
*.DS_Store
*.swp
*.out
```

Besides the .pyc file i want to ignore some other basic generic files. But when i type `git add .`, it still adds the .pyc files.

How do i solve this problem?Need some help...

Comment: Are the .pyc files already tracked? gitignore isn't used for already-tracked files, just for untracked ones.

Comment: The file needs to be named `.gitignore`, not `gitignore`.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks... Solved my error...

Comment: is there a way to untrack a file?

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/removing-a-file-from-git-source-control-but-not-from-the-source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git expects the file to be named `.gitignore`, not `gitignore` (note the period at the start of the file name).