# How to untrack a folder in NetBeans/Git?

Tags: git, netbeans-7

We have cache folder in our project files. We are working as a team and use NetBeans 7.2 and Git as CVS .

cache folder has some sub-folder inside. we don't want this folder and its sub-folders get involved in push action.

How can we untrack cache folder and its sub-folders?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/removing-a-file-from-git-source-control-but-not-from-the-source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add your cache folder to your `.gitignore`. Details on how to do that can be found [here](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files). You can commit your `.gitignore` to your repo, so the folder will also be ignored on all other machines.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the subdirectories to the toplevel `.git/info/exclude` or `.gitignore`, but I think all the users would need to do the same.