# Merge conflict although file should be ignored

Tags: git, gitignore, git-merge

I have two branches I am working in, `develop` and `staging`. First one is for development purposes, the second one is for a deployment which is basically the development code on a test deployment where I add dummy data to the database.

I keep some files from graphic design in the `develop` branch, e.g. Adobe Photoshop files. Surely I don't need or want them in my `staging` branch, so I added the folling line into my `.gitignore` file (it's a subfolder which contains all those files):

```
...
/gfx_material/
```

And I had removed the files from the `staging` branch by executing the following command on the unwanted files ([found in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936290/1828051)):

```
git rm --cached
```

Now in the `develop` branch there have been modifications on files in the `/gfx_material/` folder. And when trying to merge the files from `develop` into `staging` I get the error:

```
$ git merge develop
CONFLICT (modify/delete): gfx_material/path/file.psd deleted in HEAD and
modified in develop. Version develop of gfx_material/path/file.psd left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Why? Shouldn't this file (and others in that folder) be ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that while you deleted it on the `staging` branch, someone modified it on the `develop` branch (that's the `modify/delete` that you see in the error).  If no one had touched it, it'd be okay, but someone did and now Git doesn't know the correct course of action to take.

Also, you may have deleted the files on `staging` but that wasn't done on development.  It sounds like you're trying to use git as a deployment tool and want to strip unnecessary artifacts from the branch.  I'd recommend not using Git this way.  Rather, you should put together a script to grab the relevant pieces, and deploy them onto your server.  It may be nice to use Git that way--because it feels easy--but then you start doing things like deleting the PSD files that lead to development/merge headaches.

Comment: Yeah sure I didn't delete it on the `develop` branch - I want to keep it there. But I see, I shouldn't use git as a deployment tool... But shouldn't this work flawlessly if I have different `.gitignore` files in both branches?

Comment: No, it shouldn't.  In the develop branch, the files are still being versioned, and so Git will still track changes to them.  `.gitignore` only specifies which kind of untracked files you want to ignore.  But the files are tracked and, therefore, not ignored.  At issue is the you think they're unimportant, and deleted them, but the rest of the team thinks they are important and are modifying them.  So how should Git resolve the issue?  The answer: present a conflict and let the user decide, which is what it's doing.