# How do I completely remove a file from git source control, including all past commits?

Tags: git, version-control

If a user accidentally commits a file, let's say a file with database passwords, how do you permanently remove all instances of that file from a git repository?  It still needs to live on developers machines but not in the git repository.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing a file from Git source control but not from the source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/removing-a-file-from-git-source-control-but-not-from-the-source)

Answer (score 1):

You have to rewrite all commits containing that file. [`git filter-branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) will help you with that.

From `git help filter-branch`:

```
EXAMPLES
   Suppose you want to remove a file (containing confidential information or copyright
   violation) from all commits:

       git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm filename' HEAD

   Using --index-filter with git rm yields a significantly faster version.

       git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' HEAD
```

Of course, if you already published your commits and other people cloned it, they still have the file in their repository and might even reintroduce it if they are allowed to push to your repository.

Answer (score 1):

Github has an [article](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) that explains the process with Git.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$ bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa} my-repo.git
```

Source: [BFG Repo-Cleaner site](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)

Comment: Specifying `my-repo.git` is not necessary, just use the filename/glob and run the command in your repo root.