# How do I remove from staging but keep locally unstaged changes in Git?

Tags: git

I'm using two different computers to work on my Node.js app. I modified a plugin on one computer that's different from the other, and as a result I have all of these unstaged changes related to the installation of that plugin that I don't want to commit and push up remotely. I've been using `git gui` to pick only the changes I want committed, but there's got to be a more permanent solution.

How do I remove the files from being listed as unstaged changes while keeping the changes themselves on my local machine? I've added the directories in question to `.gitignore`, and I've followed the steps listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git) to try to refresh it, but every time I do I end up with a commit that contains the files that I don't want to be pushed up.

Comment: Please show your .gitignore file and examples of filenames you want to ignore

Comment: If your plugin's tracked (try `git ls-files path/to/plugin`) then you need to tell git to not bother checking the file, `git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/plugin`.