# How can I tell which files have been marked as "assume unchanged" in git

Tags: git

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936325/554807) shows you how to mark a file that is managed by git as "I don't want changes from the repo for this file" - IE to have your own local untracked version of that file, even though it remains under revision control by git in the remotes.

The question is "How can I tell which files have been marked this way?" ... a good thing to be able to check, if you are using this feature!

---

Note: mentioned in comments below, `skip-worktree` is probably a better tool for the job than `assume-unchanged`.  Nonetheless, this question documents how to find `assume-unchanged` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... the answer was provided in comments of the answer linked above:  `git ls-files -v` will show "assume unchanged" files as lower case letter.

So you can find them like this:

`git ls-files -v | grep ^[a-z]`

Comment: Almost but not quite. It would be `c` if the file is changed, for example (as opposed to `C`), `m` if the file has a merge pending (as opposed to `M`) etc. The unchanged assumption is marked by lowercase, but not necessarily a lowercase `h`. See `-t` and `-v` options in `git help ls-files`. `grep ^[a-z]` is much more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks!  I've updated accordingly.   Can an assume-unchanged file have a merge pending?

Comment: Haha, you might be right! I totally didn't think. Also, incidentally, I blundered into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree), suggesting `skip-worktree` is a better option for this scenario.

Comment: Yeah - it does appear that `skip-worktree` is better suited.  Meanwhile, I'm guessing that `^h` is probably sufficient OK, since the file is never seen as changed, but `^[a-z]` is probably safe anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

Slight improvement to @GreenAsJade answer:

```
git ls-files -v | grep "^[a-z]"
```

That works for zsh users.