# git status is showing "Changes not staged for commit" for files listed in .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

Let is look at the .gitignore file - to which I added mllib/pom.xml and pom.xml and even .gitignore (which should not be necessary - so something is amiss..):

```
$head .gitignore
.gitignore
mllib/pom.xml
pom.xml
```

So then let's see what files git wants to add:

```
$ git status
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   mllib/pom.xml
    modified:
```

**UPDATE** There are two comments about not "ignoring the .gitignore". But after removing the .gitignore again we get this:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   mllib/pom.xml
```

So (a)  .gitignore is showing up and (b)  the specific file that really is important not to add to a commit - mllib/pom.xml - *also* shows up.

Comment: don't ignore the ignore

Comment: Uhhhh...you might not want to ignore `.gitignore`.

Comment: If I remove .gitignore then it shows up in "Changes not staged for commit"

Comment: That's because it's not staged for commit...

Comment: After you remove the `.gitignore` from `.gitignore`, do a `git add .`.  You won't have any trouble with that XML file anymore.

Comment: Changes to .gitignore to not need to be added nor committed for them to take effect.  Git will read whatever is in the file.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `.gitignore` file doesn't mean what you think it means.<sup>1</sup>

In particular, once you have made a file "known" to git, in that it's in the index, adding that file's name to `.gitignore` has no effect.  Git already tracks the file, and it will continue to track it.

In essence, the `.gitignore` file is not actually a list of files to ignore.  Instead, when git comes across a case of an "untracked" file and is about to report it to you, the `.gitignore` contents are a list of names it should suppress.

For the `.gitignore` file itself you probably just want to `git add` the changes and commit them, since as a general rule, anyone cloning your repository probably wants to ignore the same set of untracked files, so `.gitignore` should be tracked and version-controlled.

For the XML file, however, it may be "generated content" that you don't want version-controlled, but you still want to keep it in the work-tree.  This is a bit of a problem, because git is already tracking it and will insist on continuing to version-control the file.

What you can do at this point is remove it from git's index, but not from the work-tree:

```
git rm --cached mllib/pom.xml
```

That's fine as far as it goes (git removes the file from the index and the next commit will lack that file), but it creates problems if you ever go back to a commit that *does* have the file, because git will see that it needs to create the file—you're moving from a commit in which the file does not exist (a recent one) to a commit in which it does exist (an old one)—and may complain that the contents of that file will be clobbered.  Or, even if this part works, if you then move back to a recent version, getting away from the old version, git will compare the old and new versions and see that the file has been removed ... and will *remove* `mllib/pom.xml`.

**Re-edit, 20 Oct 2016**: Use `git update-index --skip-worktree`, not `git update-index --assume-unchanged`.  This sets a more powerful bit in the index.  See [Git - Difference Between 'assume-unchanged' and 'skip-worktree'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13630849/1256452).  **Edit**: as [Schwern noted in a comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101020/git-status-is-showing-changes-not-staged-for-commit-for-files-listed-in-gitig/28101230?noredirect=1#comment44578091_28101230), you can use `git update-index --assume-unchanged` to make git not even *look* at the file for changes, rather than using `git rm --cached` to take it out of the index (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936325/14660) for details).  This is also fine as far as it goes, you just may have to do it again (or have all your co-workers do it themselves) on any other/new clones.

(You can recover from the latter by using `git show <oldrev>:mllib/pom.xml > mllib/pom.xml` to dump the file to standard output, and redirect standard output to re-create the file.)

---

<sup>1</sup>[Inconceivable!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHVjs4aobqs)

(More seriously, everyone makes this mistake.  Probably `gitignore` was the wrong name, and something like `git-screen-away-untracked` might have been better, if klunkier.  However, listing a file in `.gitignore` has other side effects as well: specifically, it [permits Git to clobber such files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345998/stop-git-from-silently-clobbering-ignorefiles-bug-in-git#comment50929165_31348457) in some cases.)

Comment: gotta upvote this - if for no other reason the use of "Inconceivable".  Too bad the proper inflections are not reproducible off of a web page.  Thx for delving into this - .gitignore is in fact well more complicated than anticipated. I will gradually learn some method to handle the local-changes-only handling required for the pom.xml

Comment: @javadba [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/936325/14660) should offer a solution to ignoring local changes to a tracked file.

Comment: @Schwern: I probably should have mentioned the `--assume-unchanged` trick.  I personally don't like it as everyone who clones the repository has to do that too, but mostly I just try to avoid getting into the situation in the first place.  (Also, added your video link! :D )

Comment: @torek It's not the best, but it's the only thing I've seen to have a file in the repository but avoid accidentally changing it (like with a `git add .`). Of course, you can contrive to not have the problem in the first place.

Comment: If I use 'git update-index --skip-worktree' and then run: 'git commit -a' will the the committing of "all" (e.g. the '-a') still ignore the skip-worktree items? or will it commit them?

Comment: @AuxiliaryJoel: Files that are in the index are included in the commit, even if they have flags set. The `git commit -a` first does the equivalent of `git add -u`; the `git add -u` step honors the `--skip-worktree` flag by not *replacing* the copy of the file that *is* in the index already, with a copy of the version that is in the work-tree. The `git commit` then goes on to use the index's copy of the file as the version that goes into the new commit. So the answer is: yes, it commits the file; but yes, it ignores the work-tree copy.

Comment: @torek Ok thanks for that.  How do I remove files from the 'staged for commit' list (locally) without effecting the actual files, and without effecting the remote/live server later on when I git pull on it?

Comment: @AuxiliaryJoel: First part first: The *staged for commit* list is the list of files in the index that *differ from* their `HEAD` copy. You can reduce the size of the list (to zero if you like) by copying from `HEAD` to index. The `git reset` command does this, e.g., `git reset -- path/to/file1 path/to/file2 subdir/` copies the two specified files, plus all files whose name starts with `subdir/`, from `HEAD` to index. Nothing here touches the work-tree.

Comment: Second part: How some *other* Git affects files in its work-tree is up to the user of the other Git. As long as that user is *you*, you can make any arrangements you like. The easy one is this: suppose you're on commit `a123456` and you run `git merge b789abc` to merge your commit `a123456` with your (just-fetched) commit `b789abc`. Suppose further that commit `b789abc` has the *same* version of the *same* files that you have in your `a123456`, and/or the *same* version of the *same* files that are in the merge base of these two commits. This `git merge` operation will not change [continued]

Comment: ... will not change any of your flies in your work-tree. I mention specific commit hash IDs here because that's how `git pull` really works internally: `git pull` runs `git fetch`, which brings over new commits. One of those new commits has some hash ID—the *same* hash ID it had when you (or whoever) created it in the Git in which you (or whoever) created it, created it. That's the hash ID that `git pull` will pass to `git merge`. What you're doing at commit time is making a snapshot. How someone else will use that snapshot in the future ... well, that's for the someone-else-in-the-future.

Answer (score 1):

After you add files to `.gitignore` and push that file to git then issue

```
git restore .
```

so then `git status` will then stop showing those files you have added to `.gitignore`