# Git ignore for nested extensions

Tags: git, nested

My project contains files that have the extension .acd; The project also automatically generates backups that are labeled project.BAK000.acd

I would like to use git-ignore to filter out all files with *.BAK*.acd, but I'm having some trouble, could anyone provide an example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Answer (score 1):

Using your project.BAK000.acd as an example, I'd try adding *.BAK*.acd in the .gitignore file