# .factorypath added to .gitignore is not taken into account

Tags: eclipse, git, project, gitignore

In `.gitignore` under the same directory there is

```
.factorypath
/.factorypath
```

added for eclipse project. But whenever any change occur in this file it is still visible as modified under git or smartgit.

Any idea why ?

Comment: Was it tracked before you added it to gitignore?

Comment: Yes it was, but .factorypath is generated by eclipse as project property. This is required file but in later it's good to have it .ignored.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely the file `.factorypath` was added to git before you excluded it in `.gitignore`. From the gitignore documentation (http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> NOTES
>   The purpose of gitignore files is to ensure that certain files not tracked by Git remain untracked.
>   To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use git rm --cached.

To show files currently tracked by git you can use `git ls-files`.
As stated in the quote above to stop tracking the file use:
`git rm --cached .factorypath`.
This will keep your working tree copy of the file but remove it from the index.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the file was previously tracked. With that in mind, this question already has been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore).