# Android SDK location not found

Tags: android, docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to test and build my android app using Jenkins locally on my machine. I'm on Linux and I launched Jenkins through docker by running the following command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins
```

Then I opened up my browser and fired Jenkins from `localhost:8080`. After the initial setup, I added the environment variable with following steps:

1. Go to Manage Jenkins
2. Configure System
3. Go to Global Properties
4. Check Environment variables
5. Add `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_HOME` environment variables in there
6. Click Apply and Save

Here's how it looks in Jenkins on my machine:
[image]

Basically followed steps from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29231580/4954322

I also added the same environment variables in my `~/.zshrc` file too:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/harry/Android/Sdk/
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/harry/Android/Sdk/
```

I'm using `Use Gradle Wrapper` in the Build section of the project configuration with the following commands:

```
clean
testDebugUnitTes
assembleDebugBuild
```

After following all of these steps, my build is still failing with message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable
or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties 
file at '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/MeteorDebugBuild/local.properties'.
```

My question is how can I fix this error and why the build is still failing with all of this setup?

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Andrey No, I have not

Answer (score 0):

I think docker containers are isolated from your Jenkins, which means that inside the container there are no environment variables `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_HOME`. What you want is:

`docker run -e ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT} -e ANDROID_HOME=${ANDROID_HOME} -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins`

I have not checked whether it works, but I hope it may be the solution to your problem