# Not version control a subdirectory?

Tags: git

I have a dir `project` containing directories `.git`, `src`, `data` and other subdirs. How can I stop sharing `data` (i.e. stop including `data` in the repository, and letting it appearing in other git repositories), while still sharing `src` and other subdirs?

Shall I move `data` out of `project`?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop tracking `data` dir:

```
git rm -r --cached data
```

**UPDATE**

As @MykolaGurov mentioned, you may also add `data` dir to `.gitignore`.

```
echo 'data' >> .gitignore
```

Comment: + .gitignore it `echo 'data' >> .gitignore`

Comment: Thanks. What if I have already tracked `data`, and then put `data` into `.gitignore`?

Comment: @Tim, as the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) say: _Files already tracked by Git are not affected_