# What happen if I put staged or committed files to .gitignore?

Tags: git

If I put a tracked file (which can be either modified, staged or committed)  to `.gitignore`, what will happen if I then run other git commands (except `git rm` or `git mv` the file that I just put inside .gitignore), for example,

- `git add -u .`, `git add -A .`, `git add .`
- `git commit`
- `git push` or `git pull`
- ...

I would like to know if putting a tracked (modified, staged or committed) into `.gitignore` will have similar consequence as `git rm`?

See my comment on a reply to my previous question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29303952/156458

Comment: In order to `commit`  a file, it should be in the *staging area*. It cannot be there if it's put in `.gitignore`.

Comment: "The purpose of gitignore files is to ensure that certain files not tracked by Git remain untracked."

Comment: My post means: After I modified a tracked file in working directory, or staged a file into the staging area, or committed it to the git repository,  I then put the file into .gitignore . What happens if I run other git commands? @MarounMaroun

Comment: @chexum. see my comment. do you mean .gitgnore can only accept untracked files, not tracked ones?

Comment: @Tim I now understood your question. Added an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot ignore a file from the staging area by simply adding it to `.gitignore`.

Adding a file to [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) "*ensure that certain files not tracked by Git remain untracked*". You should first `git rm --cached` the files you want to ignore:

```
git rm --cached file
```

Then they'll be "considered" in the `.gitignore`. See the [Ignoring files](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/):

> If you already have a file checked in, and you want to ignore it, Git will not ignore the file if you add a rule later. In those cases, you must untrack the file first, by running the following command in your terminal:

Comment: Thanks. (1) do you mean .gitgnore can only accept untracked files, not tracked ones? (2) See my comment on a reply to my previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29303952/156458

Comment: @Tim How do you define "can"? You *can* add whatever you want to the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: (1) Do you mean that, for a staged file just put inside .gitignore, it will stay in the staging area and not go into the git repository in the next `git commit`? (2) What happen to other tracked files (modified, or committed) just put inside .gitignore? (3) if I want to add a tracked (either modified, staged or committed) file into .gitignore, should I stop tracking it first by `git rm --cached file`?

Comment: @Maroun, what's the following command? or do you mean the above command?

Answer (score 1):

When you put committed files in .gitignore they will visible as modified whenever there is any change in those files. We don't want this because whatever we put files inside .gitignore those files should not go to GitHub or any other version control system. To resolve this, you need to remove those files from the git cache and then when you see git status those files will not appear as modified.

To remove the file from git cache use-

```
git rm --cached file
```