# .gitignore does not hide itself, and doesnot hide a file

Tags: git, gitignore, git-config

I have a repository, and the .gitignore is right under the repository.

When I do a `git status`, there's annoying file `src/main/resource/git.properties` that keeps showing up, and sometimes blocks me from doing a `git pull`.

I searched that `.gitignore` can help, so I added the path `src/main/resource/git.properties` to the top of the file. if I do a `cat .gitignore`, it gives

```
src/main/resource/git.properties
logs/*.log
```

I also did 
`git config --global core.excludesfile .gitignore`

Then I do `git status`,

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   src/main/resources/git.properties

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

What I expected was doing `git status` would say there's no change to the master.

Help please.

Comment: Could it be the difference between `resource` and `resources`?

Comment: I don't think `git config --global core.excludesfile .gitignore` is correct - this is supposed to be an absolute path to a single instance of a file on your whole system. I'd suggest taking that out (maybe manually edit your global git config to do so)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Comment: This is a very frequent question on the [tag:git] tag, please ensure to properly search for a solution next time.

Answer (score 1):

The `.gitignore` file does not affect files that are already checked in to the repository.  You will have to do two things:

- delete `src/main/resource/git.properties`
- add it to `.gitignore`

Once both changes are committed, it won't show up in Git any more, even if the file exists on the file system.

The use of `git config --global core.excludesfile .gitignore` is unusual... I would remove that from your global config file.  Normally you would specify a global excludes file, one with an absolute path, which applies to *all* directories.  You don't need this, because the ordinary `.gitignore` should work fine.