# Node Modules Removed After Switching Branch

Tags: git

I have `node_modules` and `bower_components` in .gitignore. Every time I switch branches, all the dependencies get removed (with exception to the globally installed ones) and I have to reinstall all of them.

I'm currently using `git stash save --keep-index --include-untracked —all`, but I was wondering if there's a simpler solution where it would retain the the directories in .gitignore after switching back from another branch.

Comment: did you ever find a solution? @danm07

Comment: partially, see answer below

Answer (score 2):

This issue had something to do with these directories being tracked in the git index prior to my recording them in .gitignore.

I did the following to resolve the issue:

1. Remove `<directory>` from .gitignore
2. `git rm -r --cached <directory>`
3. Add back `<directory>` to .gitignore
4. Stage and commit changes to

I got this from [How to stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git), and it solved my `node_modules` problem, but there's some residuals in `bower_components` that still remain tracked.

Comment: This doesn't work for me `fatal: pathspec 'node_modules/' did not match any files` please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52914838/git-moves-files-folders-with-when-checking-other-branches-although-i-use-stash-b

Comment: this didn't work for me either. @Imnotapotato, your fatal message is coming from the fact that node_modules is actually not staged (have a look inside if you have color coding).  I have tried to stage (not wait till it finishes cause it's a big directory and stop) and then git rm command works. Consequently, the next steps work as well.  However, some of the node modules still get removed when changing branch.