# How to exclude a file from git status

Tags: git

Most `hg` commands allow you to pass a `-Xfilename` argument to exclude a file that doesn't belong on your ignore list. Is there a way to do this with `git`?

I've got a script that's checking if there are any changes to the working copy, using `git status`, but I'd like it to exclude changes to itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Comment: @AlisterBulman I don't really want to stop tracking the changes to the file. I just wanted to exclude it from the single invocation of `git status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But if you're doing this in a script, then you can pipe `git status` to `grep -v` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily ignore the file with the help of

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```