# .gitignore files not ignoring certain files during git push?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

Contents of my *.gitignore* file within my project directory:

```
bin/
.settings/
.classpath
.project
MyGuide.txt
.gitignore
```

What is showing up in my github project:

[image]

Is there a reason "MyGuide.txt" and the *.gitignore* files are still being displayed when I push to my remote repo?

Comment: did you happen to `git add` those files manually? or create and push them before you put the .gitignore in place?

Comment: @radai  I'm having a hard time recalling at the moment.  Should a .gitignore be created before adding anything to the staging area?

Comment: ideally yes, it should be the 1st thing in. but you could always `git rm [file]` those files and next time you push they will be gone. also **you cant ignore the .gitignore itself** :-)

Comment: Yeah, you should check .gitignore into your repo, so you shouldn't ignore it.

Comment: @radai  gotcha, thanks!  And yeah, trying to go meta ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Comment: @radai _"you cant ignore the .gitignore itself"_ - actually you can, but you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your file is already **added** to the git repo.

Once file is added (not untracked) adding it to .gitignore will not ignore it since its already in the repo so you have to **remove** it from the repository, commit the deletion of the file and then it will be ignored.

```
# Remove any file you have already commited and you wish to ignore
git rm -rf --cached .idea/*

# now add the ignored pattern to your .gitignore file
git add -A .

# commit and push the removal of the ignored files.
git commit -m "Removed idea files"
git push
```