# How can I add these modified files to .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

When I do `git status` I see the following:

`modified:   ../.bundle/binstubs/byebug
    modified:   ../.bundle/binstubs/coderay
    modified:   ../.bundle/binstubs/erubis
    modified:   ../.bundle/binstubs/haml
    modified:   ../.bundle/binstubs/htmldiff
    modified:   ../.bundle/binstubs/iron_worker
    modified:   ../.bundle/binstubs/kramdown
    modified:   ../.bundle/binstubs/ldiff`

My .gitignore contains:

 `../.bundle/*`

But these files still show up.  How can I remove them from showing up when I type `git status`?  These are all gems, so I don't think I actually need them in my repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what have been said by murraybo, since it looks like you've already added these files to your history, even if you add them to your `.gitignore`, git will keep tracking them (unless removed from your history)

To remove/stop tracking them (without removing your local copy) execute:

`git rm --cached -r ../.bundle/`

Comment: That appears to have done it -- it is "green" as deleted, but assuming when I commit it all goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Create or change a `.gitignore` one directory level up.

Add `.bundle` to this file

Comment: one directory up:  1 *.log
  2 .bundle/*   So that doesn't seem to help.