# Run `rake assets:precompile` in development mode, but don't create unnecessary files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, gitignore

Whenever I am pushing to production (not Heroku) I am getting

```
rails assets precompile phase failed
```

I want to add a way to force my colleagues check their css code, hence I asked them all to run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

before even comiting to a branch so that they all make sure they didn't do any CSS syntax errors. Git is always generating `public/assets` folder which I don't want to add to my git repository so I added the following line in my `gitignore` -> `public/assets`. Evan that, git doesn't want to ignore my files from `public/assets`. Is there a way to ignore files generated into this folder? Do they have another path after being generated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Tried those commands and didn't work for me. I guess the route is not public/assets actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER: `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` line can be added to `.travis.yml`, Travis CI configuration file of the project, and whenever pushing to Github, Travis will do the hard work for you! The build will fail if this command is failing!

Answer (score 2):

> git doesn't want to ignore my files from public/assets

This is happening because you / your team members have already committed `public/assets` to the repo. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1139797/3284936) outlines the basic commands you need to run to remove the unwanted files / folders from you repo

1. **Commit all you current changes**
2. run `git rm -r --cached .` to remeove changed files
3. then run `git add -A` and `git commit -m 'fixes .gitignore'` like you normally would

> I want to add a way to force my colleagues check their css code

You can also automate this using a build-monitoring system from one of the continuous-integration tools (e.g. [CirclCI](http://circleci.com/)). Each time your team pushes anything to a repo, CI client can run `scss-lint` on your app's `app/assets/stylesheets` directory, and `rake assets:precompile` to make sure the new code base does not 'break' any parts of you app.

More about Continuous Integration for Rails from CirclCi: https://circleci.com/docs/language-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: I can confirm that public/assets is not in my git repo!

Comment: This is the answer!. Thanks