# How to remove files from under Git control?

Tags: git

I have occasionally added `.class` files under Git control. Now I have headaches. Each push I am obliged to manually remove files from list and each pull it warns me to stash chenged files.

How to completely remove some files from under Git?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Answer (score 1):

You use [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Create a `.gitignore` file in your root directory (don't forget the period in front) and add the name of the files you want git to ignore in it:

```
*.class
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you begin experimenting with your valuable code, I suggest to create a backup first.

First, you should tell git to ignore those files in the future, by writing `*.class` into the .gitignore file.

The next thing is, to tell git to not track those files anymore, by `git rm --cached <file>`

If you've pushed something sensitive, and want to remove the history from the repository, follow the github documentation about this topic: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/