# How to untrack modified files without deleting them from the Git repository

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods

I'm working with another developer on an iOS application.

Once they downloaded the project, they had to amend some of the directories for their dependencies, and change the path for one of the dependencies in their podfile like so:

pod 'ThePod', :path => ‘/Users/TheirName/Desktop/DifferentFolderName/the-sdk’

Then they run pod update as to install the dependencies.

My issue is that all these files showed up as modified files, and once pushed, if I pull the files they change the dependency directories on my end.

Is there a way we can untrack all of these modified files without deleting them from the repository? Just so I can pull them without having them all deleted from my end.

Comment: I won't close this as a duplicate just yet, but see https://stackoverflow.com/q/936249/1256452. The short answer is that the question is not really well formed, since you can't delete *files* from a *repository:* the repository doesn't hold files, it holds *commits*. (Meanwhile, you cannot change any existing commit, though you can add new commits, and stop using old commits.)

Comment: My apologies as I'm new to this- but this leaves me confused. My end goal is to not have Github delete the files from the developer who pulls my changes after I untrack them using git rm -r --cached "file"

Comment: The problem here is that these files should never have been committed in the first place, as they contain installation dependent configuration data. At most, the repository itself should contain installation *in*-dependent configuration data, e.g., a prototype configuration that something—the user, or the install process— *copies* to the dependent file that is never stored in Git at all, that is used later. But now it's too late to do it the right way, so see the other Q&A for various workarounds. (There's never time to do it right at the start, so we all spend time fixing later... :-) )

Comment: Looks like there will be no escaping the ominous merge conflicts...Thank you for the help!