# I've committed folders that I should ignore. How can I start to ignore now?

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitignore

I've committed time ago many folders that I should had ignored. I mean, the folders  `.vs` (and its content) into every `Visual Studio` project.

That said, I've many folders/projects with `.vs` into it, to the same repo.

How can I untrack all of them and start ignoring now?

Is there a recursive `git rm -r --cached`? Or do I need to specify every path? And than I should add `*/.vs` on `gitignore` right?

Comment: Do you need to remove them from your remote repository ?

Comment: @matthiasbe: it would be great. I mean: I could keep them in the "past" commits, but I'd like to remove it now, and for the future commits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes there is a `git rm -r --cached` command.

Once you have committed your updated .gitignore file along with other changes,
un-track it by doing a `git rm -r --cached .` and then `git add .`

Now those files should be excluded from tracking.

Finally, `git commit -m "Untrack unnecessary files"`

Comment: So, first I add `.vs/` to `.gitignore`. Than I commit it. Than? Not sure how to untrack all `.vs/` folders already tracked. Can you show to me the real list of commands?

Comment: To give more details : 1) add `*.vs` to .gitignore 2) `git rm -r --cached *.vs` in your root folder 3) commit your changes.

Comment: Note that this will delete the files from the other contributors to your repo. See more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/936290/6400167)

Comment: @matthiasbe: in fact if I push these changes, and another user who is collaborating pull again from my remote repo, this will delete his own ".vs" folders on him local repo. Right?

Comment: @markzzz exactly yes. You could ask them to store the *.vs folders before they pull you changes from origin, and then to put the folders back after the pull

Comment: @matthiasbe: I see. What if I want to do the same but keep files on every repo? Is it possibile? Some fancy commands?

Comment: @markzzz I don't know any magic potion to do that, but [this](https://gist.github.com/scy/6636390) seems to really tackle this issue