# Trying to ignore .pyc extension in .gitignore

Tags: git

I am trying to ignore all .pyc extensions in the repository
my .gitignore file looks like this

```
.idea
*.rdb
# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
__pycache__/
*.py[cod]
*.pyc
__pycache__/
```

however when I do `git status`. I get information on modified files like this

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .DS_Store
    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   Device/__init__.py
    modified:   Device/admin.py
    modified:   Device/apps.py
    modified:   Device/migrations/0001_initial.py
    modified:   Device/migrations/__init__.py
    modified:   Employee/__init__.py
    modified:   Employee/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-35.pyc
```

Notice the last file .pyc is shown as modified and also the foled **pycache** which is added to .gitignore also gets shown. How do I get git to ignore them ?

Comment: Those files are *already in your repository*, and are currently tracked (i.e., in your index). Listing them in `.gitignore` has no effect. You must make them untracked: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/how-to-stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git

Answer (score 9):

It seems like your `.pyc` file was added before you commited the `.gitignore`.

Try to first remove everything that is tracked by:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

OR:

```
git rm -r --cached Employee/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-35.pyc
```

Now, try:

```
git add .
```