# I have 5 files I want to ignore in git. Updated my .gitignore to include them but get "local changes to the following files would be overwritten"

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have 5 files that I want to ignore in git on my test server. I updated my git ignore file to include them but I still get an error saying "You local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout" and am unable to proceed with the checkout.  I am on the server and see the .gitignore file as been updated. The error lists the problematic files under the error message:

```
path\to\file_a
path\to\file_b
path\to\file_c
path\to\file_d
path\to\file_e
```

My .gitignore file looks like the below:

```
# Directories #
###############
# Ignore everything:
/*

# Except for the web, database, and company web directories:
!web/
!database/
!cron/
!includes/
!.gitignore

# But still ignore these directories and files:
path/to/file_a
path/to/file_b
path/to/file_c
path/to/file_d
path/to/file_e
```

I believe I should not get the git error because I have listed the files in the .gitignore

I did the rm --cahced path\to\file method and that did not work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBF6k.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/how-to-stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

`.gitignroe` doesn't apply to files that are tracked in git. In addition to adding them to `.gitignore`, you need to remove these files from git's tracking by using `git rm --cached`. 
(note: the `--cached` flag removes the files from git's tracking but preserves them in the working directory, so you don't lose your local changes)

```
$ git rm --cached path/to/file_a path/to/file_b path/to/file_c path/to/file_d path/to/file_e
```

Comment: I tried that and updated the post to include a screen shot of what happened when I tried to do a checkout after that.

Comment: @SJW525 did you still add them to `.gitignore`? Did you commit those changes?

Comment: Yes. I committed. Do I also have to push them? I am directly on the server doing this.