# Why is git pushing my files normally, even if they are handled by git-LFS?

Tags: git, commit, git-lfs

I have the problem that, in my repo, I have to upload an essential `*.lm` dictionary file which is about 380mb of size.
It actually is tracked by `git-lfs` and it also is being uploaded to `git-lfs`. My problem is, that besides `git-lfs`, git also uploads this file to the repo, so at the end it fails, because you can't upload files bigger than 100mb.

I already tried to clean my repo with bfg and `git-lfs import` to migrate my repo to lfs. None of them worked, it still keeps uploading the files to both `lfs` and the normal repo.

I really don't know what to do, it already worked in the history, now it does not anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [How to stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/how-to-stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

In particular, you would need to remove the file from being tracked. What the answer in the link recommends is `git rm --cached <file-name>`.

You would then need to add it to your `.gitignore`

Comment: This does not work. If i add the file to `.gitignore`, it will be completely ignored by git, even by `git-lfs`.

Comment: What does your `.gitattributes` file look like?

Comment: It was my mistake - something was wrong with my repository, I did a complete reset to the last remote state - now it works, but nothing wrong with git-lfs. But thanks for your help!