# Stop tracking file locally, but let other repo users keep tracking it?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, gitignore, git-rm

I'm collaborating on an IntelliJ IDEA project using Git and GitHub. The original creator of the repo added the IntelliJ `.idea` folder to the repo, and I find it annoying to see changes to IDE files constantly popping up in the commit dialog. The `.idea` folder is in fact added to `.gitignore`, but that happened after they were already tracked.

I removed the folder from the local repo using `git rm --cached -r -f .idea/`, which to my understanding removes the files from the repo.

**However**, other collaborators still want to be able to commit and push their changes to the `.idea` folder. So I just want to ignore the `.idea` folder locally.

The folder and it's contents show up in the commit dialog as `deleted` right now, and I'm worried that if I commit and push now, it will also affect other collaborators - right? What should I do to just ignore this folder locally but not affect others who still want to be able to commit and push their changes to the folder? Is this even possible?

Comment: Use `skip-worktree` feature: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/717372

Comment: @Philippe Thanks, I just found and tried that command, and it worked - although I had to first add back the folder to the repo, and then for some reason run the `skip-worktree` command on each file inside the `.idea` folder. Simply running it on the folder seemed to work, but changes still showed up in `git status` and the IntelliJ commit dialog. I found the answer here useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40272289/930640

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `git update-index --skip-worktree [file]`.

As pointed out in the comments, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree/13631525#13631525) provides more insight.

Comment: Once again, bad use of ` assume-unchanged` (for perf). Should be `skip-worktree` (to ignore locally): https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/717372 I don't know why most people are wrong on most of the stackoverflow answers...

Comment: Oh.. That's right. My bad! Updating the answer with correct info.