# Gitignore '*.' does not ignore some vim undo files (.un~)

Tags: git, vim, gitignore

Vim creates ignore files. For example, the file `foo.bar`, would have an associated: `.foo.bar.un~`.

I'm trying to get git to ignore all hidden files, with the exception of `.gitignore`:

```
.*
!.gitignore
```

However, this misses *some* undo files.

Running git check-ignore confirms that:
`public/.index.html.un~` is caught by `.*`, but `src/screens/.HomeScreen.js.un~` is not caught by anything...

The only difference that I can see is that it's two directories in, rather than one, but this shouldn't make a difference, from my understanding of the gitignore format.

Comment: I ran a test and found `src/screens/.HomeScreen.js.un~` was ignored as expected. Is it possible that you have already added and committed `src/screens/.HomeScreen.js.un~`?

Comment: @ElpieKay Ah... I thought that adding a file to gitignore would remove it from the repo, even if it had been committed before. I get the impression that that's wrong!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/how-to-stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Comment: @Alex no if you explicitly ask git to track a file it will