# How can I stop monitoring a file when I use Github in Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I hope to stop monitoring the file misc.xml, and don't commit the change of file to Github. How can I do? Thanks!

And more, all files under the folder .idea should be ignore when I use Git, right?

**The Image**

[image]

Comment: Please see my git command line answer as the alternative to Usama's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the file/folder to your `.gitignore` file (project-level)

Go to the Terminal in Android Studio and type in these commands:

`git rm -r the-directory-to-remove`

The above command will remove the specified directory from git.

`git commit -m "Delete .idea folder"`

The above command commits the changes, you can change "Delete .idea folder" to whatever you like.

`git push origin <your-git-branch>`

The above command pushes the changes to Github (or BitBucket).

Now, if you want to delete the file from Github/BitBucket ONLY but not from the entire filesystem, run `git rm -r --cached myFolder`
instead of the first command.

Answer (score 0):

Add the path of file or folder in .gitignore file which located in project root directory. If not make a file with name .gitignore .

Here is the documentation

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

[Example](https://github.com/UsamaAshraf82/Web-Project/blob/master/.gitignore) of .gitignore file might be helpful

Comment: Thanks! If I hope to stop monitoring the file misc.xml, and don't commit the change of file to Github. How can I do?

Comment: Please Refer to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/how-to-stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks! Can I do that in Android Studio UI ?

Comment: Sorry! I am unable to find any option for that in Android Studio, UI but you can always go to git command line for these types of operations