# Adding Git Ignore for Xcode Pods folder does not work

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cocoapods

I added a git ignore file to my Xcode project with the following commands: `touch .gitignore` then `open .gitignore` and copy and pasted this into the [git ignore content](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Swift.gitignore) (and uncommented the line that had `Pods/` line) and saved the file.

But when I still try to commit (have already committed numerous times) in Xcode, the Pods file is still there and already checked to commit.

**How can I have my Pod file not be checked and have the git ignore work with my Xcode project?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is generic to how git works. Since you've already committed the `Pods/` directory, you'll want to first make a commit that removes them. You can title this commit "Remove Pods". Do not edit the `.gitignore` file in this commit or else the delete will not be respected.

After you've made that commit, add the `.gitignore` file with the `Pods/` line uncommented and make another commit title say "Add .gitignore file".

From now on, changes to the `Pods/` directory will not be checked in.

Comment: I never committed the Pods file but i still did `git rm -r Pods` in terminal just incase and committed the gitignore file. But when I go to commit in Xcode or even terminal all of the files in Pods is still marked to be committed. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/how-to-stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git?rq=1