# Why git pull from external branch I got several conflict errors in /vendor directory

Tags: laravel, git

Making pull of Laravel 5 app from external branch I got several conflict errors like

```
error: refusing to lose untracked file at 'vendor/composer/autoload_static.php'                                                                                                                                        
CONFLICT (modify/delete): vendor/composer/autoload_real.php deleted in HEAD and modified in b871903544566b6c1fd662ac67e7987f1ecc8643. Version b871903544566b6c1fd662ac67e7987f1ecc8643 of vendor/composer/autoload_real.php left in tree.
```

but in .gitignore file I have vendor directory:

```
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
/.idea

.env
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log

composer.lock
package-lock.json
1.txt
```

I wonder why such errors and how to fix them?
I suppose there is no sense in manually editing files inside of /vendor ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's not a normal vendor package, it the autoload generated by composer.

Run this command to generate the file anew to fix the error.

`compser dump-autoload`

But what you really should do is to remove the autoload from your git:

- delete the tracked file & commit the change
- add it to the ignore list (it should be already ignored)
- push
- run command `dump-autoload` on every installation after pull

OR follow these instructions [How to stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/how-to-stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git/40272289) and the do step 4