# IntelliJ: Why are these files created when I run a Kotlin file and how to ignore them?

Tags: git, kotlin, intellij-idea, version-control, intellij-14

I feel silly asking this question but haven't been able to find a solution yet. Every time I `run` my project in IntellliJ I notice that a lot of additional files are created. I'd like to learn why these are created (am I doing something wrong?) and how can I remove them from version control. Below you'll see the files created and a screenshot of what I see. Thanks so much for your help in advance!

```
algorithms-and-data-structures.kotlin_module
build-history.bin
buildOutputCleanup.lock
class-fq-name-to-source.tab
class-fq-name-to-source.tab.keystream
class-fq-name-to-source.tab.keystream.len
class-fq-name-to-source.tab.len
class-fq-name-to-source.tab.values.at
class-fq-name-to-source.tab_i
counters.tab
DynamicArray.class
DynamicArrayKt.class
executionHistory.bin
executionHistory.lock
file-to-id.tab
file-to-id.tab.keystream
file-to-id.tab.keystream.len
file-to-id.tab.len
file-to-id.tab.values.at
file-to-id.tab_i
fileHashes.bin
fileHashes.lock
HashTable.class
HashTableKt.class
id-to-file.tab
id-to-file.tab.keystream
id-to-file.tab.keystream.len
id-to-file.tab.len
id-to-file.tab.values.at
id-to-file.tab_i
internal-name-to-source.tab
internal-name-to-source.tab.keystream
internal-name-to-source.tab.keystream.len
internal-name-to-source.tab.len
internal-name-to-source.tab.values.at
internal-name-to-source.tab_i
last-build.bin
lookups.tab
lookups.tab.keystream
lookups.tab.keystream.len
lookups.tab.len
lookups.tab.values.at
lookups.tab_i
outputFiles.bin
package-parts.tab
package-parts.tab.keystream
package-parts.tab.keystream.len
package-parts.tab.len
package-parts.tab.values.at
package-parts.tab_i
proto.tab
proto.tab.keystream
proto.tab.keystream.len
proto.tab.len
proto.tab.values.at
proto.tab_i
source-to-classes.tab
source-to-classes.tab.keystream
source-to-classes.tab.keystream.len
source-to-classes.tab.len
source-to-classes.tab.values.at
source-to-classes.tab_i
source-to-output.tab
source-to-output.tab.keystream
source-to-output.tab.keystream.len
source-to-output.tab.len
source-to-output.tab.values.at
source-to-output.tab_i
Unversioned Files
```

[image: version control in IntelliJ showing odd files]

Comment: These files are the internal cache of Gradle and Kotlin compiler. You need to add `.gradle` and `build` folders to the .gitignore file (see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: Thanks so much! I added `.gradle` and `build` to the `.gitignore` and to `.git/info/exclude` but those files continue to show up under `Default Changelist` if I do a "Build > Rebuild Project".

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/how-to-stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git

Comment: thank you so much @МихаилНафталь!! Clearing the git cache solved my issue! If you want to add it as an answer below I will mark it as the correct answer. 